# How To Check that the First letter in string is a number

Tags: php

I was trying to find a quick and easy method to check if the first letter in a string is a number. I already tried : `is_numeric($mystring[0]);` but does not work, thanks for your help!

Comment: It should only fail (by issuing a notice) if you have an empty string - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/E8IUF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use substr function, to specify the number of characters to be tested:
`is_numeric(substr($mystring, 0, 1))`  or you can use  `preg_match('/^\d/', $mystring);`

Comment: it works thanks for your help!